# ngOnInit data is undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to query my database for a list of templates. I want to print these checkout templates on my frontend view but I get returned undefined when I call my service class.

checkout.component.ts:

```ts
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  templates: Template[] = [];

  constructor(public checkoutService: CheckoutService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    try {
      const templates = this.checkoutService.getTemplates();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(templates))
    } catch (err) {

      console.log(err)
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

When I console.log the templates from the checkout service, it comes out as undefined.
checkout.service.ts:

```ts
export class CheckoutService {
  private url = "http://localhost:3000/checkout";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}


  getTemplates() {
    this.http.get<{ templates: Template[] }>(this.url).subscribe(data => {
      return data;
    })

  }
}
```

This is the http://localhost:3000/checkout endpoint on the backend
(*THIS CORRECTLY RETURNS THE DATA*):

```ts
router.get("", (req, res, next) => {
  var templates = [];
  var realTemps = [];
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ");
  const decoded = jwt.verify(token[1], 'secretkey');
  decodedFactoryId = decoded.factoryId

  Template.findAllByFactoryId(decodedFactoryId)
    .then((results) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        // THIS IS AN AVOIDABLE LOOP, 
        // TODO: quadratic time must be prevented by correctly formatting the data
        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
          if (results[i][j].id) {
            templates.push(results[i][j].id)
          }
        }
      }
    }).then(() => {
      // Promise.all
      return Promise.all(templates.map(template =>
        Template.findByTemplateId(template).then(result => {
          console.log("here is the result: " + JSON.stringify(result[0]))
          realTemps.push(result);
        })
      ));
    })
    .then(() => {
      return realTemps;
    })

})
```

When I try to console.log the getTemplates() code:

```ts
getTemplates(): Observable<{templates: Template[]}> {
    console.log( JSON.stringify(this.http.get<{templates: Template[] }>(this.url)))
    return this.http.get<{templates: Template[] }>(this.url)
}
```

I get this printed in the console, instead of the data:

```json
{
  "_isScalar": false,
  "source": {
    "_isScalar": false,
    "source": {
      "_isScalar": false,
      "source": {
        "_isScalar": false
      },
      "operator": {
        "concurrent": 1
      }
    },
    "operator": {}
  },
  "operator": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method on your service doesn't return anything. That is why you're getting undefined.

The problem is that you are defining the observable and immediately subscribing to it in your service. The return statement inside your subscribe method is relative to the subscribe callback, not your service, so it doesn't do anything here.

Instead, what you need to do is return the observable from your service method like this:

```
getTemplates(): Observable<{templates: Template[]}> {
   return this.http.get<{templates: Template[] }>(this.url)
 })
```

And then subscibe to it in the ngOnInit method in your component like this:

```
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  templates: Template[];

  constructor(public checkoutService: CheckoutService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkoutService.getTemplates().subscribe(({templates}) => this.templates = templates)
  }
```

You also don't need to explicitly state the return type of the ngOnInit, nor do you need to wrap this in a try/catch. Error handling is a bit different with observables.

Comment: Thank you, Charles!
In the code you provided, this.templates has an error: "Type '{ templates: Template[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Template[]'.ts(2322)"

This must mean that it is still in array form, so would I need to do this.templates=templates[0]? How could this be fixed?

Comment: @xxcapzxx That is my mistake. I edited my answer to add curly brackets to destructure the templates array from your observable response.The issue was that your component expects an array of template objects, but my initial answer assigned an object with an attribute "templates" whose value was an array of templates. The answer should work now.

Comment: Thank you. It still seems that when I console.log the this.templates, I get returned with an empty array [] in the  console. I added a console log statement to my post (on the bottom) to see if there was any data being returned.

Comment: @xxcapzxx if you console.logged `this.templates` from the component, then your request is returning an empty array. The output you saw when you logged the service method is what you would expect to see: an Observable. If you want more information, put a console log inside the subscribe callback on your component to see what the observable is returning.

Comment: The following doesn't print anything at all?
`ngOnInit(): void {
    this.checkoutService.getTemplates().subscribe(({ templates }) => {
      console.log(templates)
    });
  }`

Comment: @xxcapzxx look at your network tab. Is any request being sent from Angular?

Comment: Yes, but nothing related to the data being outputted. Perhaps its a typical error with data in the NgOnInit method?

Comment: @xxcapzxx check the response content. If the network tab shows a request being sent, then the ngOnInit is correctly triggering a request. If `templates` is empty, then there are 3 possibilities: 1) I made a mistake in my answer in the destructuring, or 2) the response is actually empty, or 3) the response doesn't have a field called templates. Try changing `({ templates })` to just `response`, and log that.

Comment: A request is being sent, and templates is not empty. Even if I remove  ({templates}) and replace it with () and make it console.log("random text") inside the subscription, nothing gets printed. It seems like nothing will execute inside the subscribe.

Comment: @xxcapzxx If a request is being sent, then the result will be in the subscribe callback (assuming there is no error on the request). Look at the request in your network tab. You can see the results there. If that isn't empty, then whatever the contents are will be passed to your subscribe callback. You can access it by doing `.subscribe(result => console.log(result))`